# Is there an alternative for the wiki module that has been dropped in v7 of OpenERP?

Tags: wiki, odoo

As you may have noticed, the `wiki` module has been dropped in v7 of OpenERP.

The question is: what alternatives are there it? Is there any community module available or in the works, providing wiki (or even markdown) documents?

Comment: Not sure if you know, but the wiki module has been renamed to "document_page" in v7, and works in pure HTML/wysiwyg mode now. See release notes section 8.3: http://v6.openerp.com/node/1269#h.k5rq39nvqtb4 When migrating to 7.0, existing wiki pages have to be transformed to HTML. I don't know if that qualifies as an alternative "wiki" solution in your eyes, though.

Comment: @odony Thanks for the comment. AFAIK point of `wiki` (and markdown) is to save regular users from learning HTML. AFAIK the "Document Pages" edition is plain text, not rich-text wysiwyg, like MediaWiki's friendly edit box.

Comment: @odony Give same in answer so DReispt can select it :). Otherwise this question will be open always :)

Comment: @DReispt the contents of Document Pages should of course be edited in wysiwyg mode, it was not due to a missing ``widget=html`` option in the view (fixed now). Another issue causes the editable area to be too narrow initially in all editable wysiwyg fields, should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a little more info regarding what I said in comments.

In OpenERP 7.0, the wiki module has been renamed/revamped into the `document_page` module. You may find this mentioned in the last section ([8.3 Renamed Modules](http://v6.openerp.com/node/1269#h.k5rq39nvqtb4)) of the OpenERP 7.0 [Release Notes](http://v6.openerp.com/node/1269). It now uses a simple WYSIWYG/HTML editor and stores the pages as HTML, instead of the previous wiki/markdown-based syntax. Therefore you may or may not see it as a true "wiki alternative". The goal is to make it easier and more flexible to use, effectively providing a minimalist CMS system inside OpenERP: you can use it to add static pages in your regular OpenERP menu (or your OpenERP portal), organize them in section/categories, etc., using freely editable HTML (you can edit the HTML source if needed), while preserving their

Note that several issues in the initial 7.0 release might temporarily make the document pages less user-friendly than they should: the WYSIWYG editor was not enabled in all cases in edit mode (fixed now) and the editor is sometimes too narrow (should be fixed soon).

On a related topic, it may also be interesting to know that OpenERP 7.0 provides a collaborative writing solution via the new `pad` module, allowing you to embed [etherpad-lite](http://etherpad.org/) pads in your documents. It's integrated with the `project` and the `note` modules, and you can use it easily for your own custom modules as well.

Comment: Well, writing in HTML surely is not a replacement for writing in Wiki markup, but a good WYSIWYG widget would overcome that. Although, looking into the code I see that a `wiky.js` library is used to convert Wiki tags to HTML, but it doesn't even support bold or italic. It's a pity that a better library wasn't used for this.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenERP Knowledge Addons](https://launchpad.net/knowledge-addons) features a module to [support MediaWiki syntax](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~therp-nl/knowledge-addons/6.1/view/head:/wiki_wikimedia/__openerp__.py) (currently only available/verified for v6.1).